# perl remove substring before a character

Tags: string, perl, substring

I've got the following string: 
`get_url.pl?critic_name=A_O_Scott`.

I've got the following regex which returns anything before the `=` but i cant seem to get it to remove before the `?`

```
$string=~ s/\=.*$//;
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Note that regex modifies `$string`, which may not be what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an existing parser rather than writing your own.

```
use URI             qw( );
use URI::QueryParam qw( );

my $uri = URI->new('get_url.pl?critic_name=A_O_Scott', 'http');
```

Then, if you want the name of the first parameter,

```
my ($first_param_name) = $uri->query_param();
```

That said, most of the time, you'd want a hash of the parameters.

```
my %params = $uri->query_form();
```

---

You said you wanted to *remove* `get_url.pl`, but the other answers assumed that's the part you wanted to *keep*. If you want the part before the query, you can use

```
use URI qw( );

my $uri = URI->new('get_url.pl?critic_name=A_O_Scott', 'http');
$uri->query(undef);

print("$uri\n");
```

Comment: using the %params, if i print the values i get critic_name and A_O_Scott. how can i make it so only A_O_Scott prints?

Comment: `$params{critic_name}`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($string =~ /^(.*)\?(.*)$/) {
    my $first_bit = $1;
    my $second_bit = $2;
}
```

For the example string `a?b`, this will set `$first_bit` to the string `a` and `$second_bit` to the string `b`.